# Filter a collection by NOT FIND_IN_SET

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, database, attributes, collection

I need to filter a collection by a negative `FIND_IN_SET`.

I know I can do this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    'attribute_code',
    [['finset' => 4], ['null' => true]]
);
```

This filters the collection by `FIND_IN_SET(...) OR value IS NULL`. But the `FIND_IN_SET` needs to be negative (`NOT FIND_IN_SET`). How can I achieve this?

Do I really need to create a custom `Zend_Db_Expr` for this?

**Edit:** After the answer of @Marius I solved this with `Zend_Db_Expr`. In case anyone else bumps into this 'issue', here's how I solved it:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where(
    new \Zend_Db_Expr(
        sprintf('NOT FIND_IN_SET(%1$d, at_excluded_customer_groups.value) OR at_excluded_customer_groups.value IS NULL',
            $customerGroupId
        )
    )
);
```

My situation was to filter on customer group ID or NULL.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer, so you can accept it. People may miss it if you keep it in your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you have to create a `Zend_Db_Expr` for it.
There is no support for `NOT FIND_IN_SET`.
You can see all supported conditions in [`Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::prepareSqlCondition`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php#L2913).

```
    $conditionKeyMap = array(
        'eq'            => "{{fieldName}} = ?",
        'neq'           => "{{fieldName}} != ?",
        'like'          => "{{fieldName}} LIKE ?",
        'nlike'         => "{{fieldName}} NOT LIKE ?",
        'in'            => "{{fieldName}} IN(?)",
        'nin'           => "{{fieldName}} NOT IN(?)",
        'is'            => "{{fieldName}} IS ?",
        'notnull'       => "{{fieldName}} IS NOT NULL",
        'null'          => "{{fieldName}} IS NULL",
        'gt'            => "{{fieldName}} > ?",
        'lt'            => "{{fieldName}} < ?",
        'gteq'          => "{{fieldName}} >= ?",
        'lteq'          => "{{fieldName}} <= ?",
        'finset'        => "FIND_IN_SET(?, {{fieldName}})",
        'regexp'        => "{{fieldName}} REGEXP ?",
        'from'          => "{{fieldName}} >= ?",
        'to'            => "{{fieldName}} <= ?",
        'seq'           => null,
        'sneq'          => null
    );
```

As you can see, there is nothing similar to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw this list indeed, but I wondered if there was any filter or inversion method that could override these. I fixed it in the meanwhile with `Zend_Db_Expr`

Answer (score 1):

Using `nin` with an array of values should be enough I reckon:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    'attribute_code',
    [['nin' => [4, 5]], ['null' => true]]
);
```

Comment: that does not work if the values of the attribute for a product are stored in a single column concatenated by comma `1,2,3,4`. That's what find in set does. It splits the value by comma and checks for matching values.

Comment: @Marius hmmm yeah that makes sense. As the OP only provided one value I wasn't sure the reason why he used find_in_set

Comment: because he wants all the values from the field `1,2,3` that does not contain a 4.

Comment: You guys are right, it's all about multiselect values stored in the varchar table... Those are separated by a comma and I want to use raw SQL-power to filter on this, not perform multiple queries.