# Magento 2, opposite of finset needed to filter a product collection

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter

I have a problem in a product collection that I need to filter.
I have a multiselect list with countries. When a selection is made the products need to be hidden from these countries.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('available_not_for_countries', array(array('nin' => $billingCountry),array('null' => true)));
```

I know I need the opposite of finset like NOT FIND_IN_SET but I have no idea how to create the new Zend_Db_Expr for this in this filter.

Comment: What is the type of $billingCountry? Is it array? Or a string with comma-separated values?

Comment: available_not_for_countries is a multiselect attribute.
$billingCountry is the default-billing address country of a logged in customer.
So this can be "DE","ES" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->where('NOT FIND_IN_SET(?, available_not_for_countries)', $billingCountry);
```

Comment: It's not working as $billingCountry is not comma seperated. But returns one value like "DE" or "BE".
The attribute "available_not_for_countries" returns a multiselect of countries where products should not be visible. So based on the billingaddress country we know if we can show a product or not.

Comment: Okay, so $billingCountry is a string and "available_not_for_countries" is a comma-separated list of countries? eg. "DE,BE" ?

Comment: Yes indeed. As an example. I also have this filter and it works perfect:

   ->addAttributeToFilter('available_for_countries', array(array('finset' => $billingCountry),array('null' => true)));

However the opposite of finset isn't available in Magento2 like you can see here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151142/filter-a-collection-by-not-find-in-set

Comment: Can not use the answer field. (someone help?) so here is the answer:
I solved it thanks to the example of @Giel Beelen his feedback on: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151142/filter-a-collection-by-not-find-in-set.

My final result was:

            ->getSelect()->where(
            new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                sprintf('NOT FIND_IN_SET(%1$d, available_not_for_countries) OR available_not_for_countries IS NULL',
                    $billingCountryNav
                )
            )
        );

Answer (score 0):

Magento has
'nfinset'       => "NOT FIND_IN_SET(?, {{fieldName}})",